# Multiple real time plots in matlab from arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino

I hope you can help me.

I have connected 3 sensors to an Arduino, and I´m sending the data to the serial port simultaneously.

arduino code is

```
 unsigned int pres; 
 unsigned int temp; 
 unsigned int fluidrate;
 void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
pres = analogRead(0);
temp = analogRead(1);
fluidrate =  analogRead(2);
Serial.print(pres);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(temp);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(fluidrate);
Serial.print("\n");
delay(1000);
```

}
The data in serial monitor of arduino is

```
257    7    14
273    23   46
327    77   154
340    90   180
345    95   190
352    102  204
```

Matlab code is

```
clear all
clc
arduino=serial('COM8','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(arduino); 
 x=linspace(1,100);
 numcols = 1; 
 y = {};
 for i=1:length(x);    
 data =fscanf(arduino,'%f'); 
     IncomingString = char(data);
     IncomingString = regexp(IncomingString, '\s*', 'split');
     pres(i,1)= IncomingString(1,1); 
     temp(i,1)= IncomingString(1,2); 
     fluidrate(i,1)= IncomingString(1,3); 
 end
fclose(arduino);
Plotpres = str2double(pres);
figure(1)
plot(Plotpres);
title('pressure'); xlabel('Samples'); ylabel('pres in bar');
Plottemp = str2double(temp); 
figure(2)
plot(Plottemp);
title('temperature'); xlabel('Samples'); ylabel('temp in C');
Plotfluidrate = str2double(fluidrate); 
figure(3)
plot(Plotfluidrate);
title('fluidrate'); xlabel('Samples'); ylabel('fluidrate in l/min');
```

I am getting error ??? Error using ==> regexp The first argument (STRING) must be a one-dimensional array of char or cell arrays of strings.

Error in ==> monitorsystem at 11 IncomingString = regexp(IncomingString, '\s*', 'split');

Please help me to get the output

Comment: Looks ike IncomingString is not the size expected. What format has that string?

Comment: Why are you using `%f` for integers? Further fscanf already converts ascii data to double, don't think `char(data)` returns anything usefull in this case. Please tell us what `data` is and how you expect it to be processed.